# Arff File - Nominal Value not declared in header.

Tags: weka, arff

I am generating an .arff file using a Java program. The file has about 600 attributes.

I am unable to open the file in Weka Explorer. 
It says: "nominal value not declared in header, read Token[0], line 626."

Here is the first attribute line: @attribute vantuono numeric
Here are the first few chars of line 626: 0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1...

**Why is WEKA unable to parse '0' as a numeric value?**

Interestingly, this happens only in this file. I have other files with numeric attributes accepting '0' for a value.

Comment: Maybe there's a wrong line ending on the line before?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff The new line seems fine. I am using the same BufferedWriter.newLine() function in all my files.

Comment: So how did you resolve it?

Comment: In order to avoid such mistakes, you should use the Weka API to create ARFF files, see Weka Wiki: [Creating ARFF file](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/formats_and_processing/creating_arff_file/)

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that your declaration is correct? The [WEKA FAQ](http://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+file+doesn%27t+load) says:

> **nominal value not declared in header, read Token[X], line Y**
>
> If you get this error message than you seem to have declared a nominal attribute in the ARFF header section, but Weka came across a value (**"X"**) in the data (in line **Y**) for this particular attribute that wasn't listed as possible value.
>   **All** nominal values that appear in the data must be declared in the header.

There is also a [bug regarding sparse ARFF files](http://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+%28stable+version%29#Sparse%20ARFF%20files)

Comment: I had a similar issue.  It was a case of my feature vector array had an extra element and that was the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the memory to accommodate all the rows using -B #noOfRecords option.

java weka.core.converters.CSVLoader filename.csv filename.arff -B 33000

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error, it's more likely that in your dataset (after the line @data), you kept the HEADER (column names) that you have already declared. Please remove that header line, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. Then I saw that my program puts an extra Apostrophe. When I remove the Apostrophe it works

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem and it costed me so you won't be costed Okay. Just put the class attribute last, and ensure the attributes are in order as in the text.